# pandas.read_csv() How to exclude specific separtor combinations

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import-from-csv

I have a csv like:

file:

```
1;a;3;4
1;2;b;4
1;[a;b];3;4
```

Loading like pd.from_csv(file, sep=';')

returns error:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line
> 3, saw 5

as the `[a;b]` is seen as a separator. Is there a way to exclude `;` when in `[ ]`

Thanks

p.s. changing the file is impossible due to reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `;(?![^\[]*\])` as regex separator to match only semicolons not inside brackets:

```
pd.read_csv(filename, sep=r';(?![^\[]*\])', engine='python')
```

demo:

```
text = '''1;a;3;4
1;2;b;4
1;[a;b];3;4
'''

import io
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep=r';(?![^\[]*\])', engine='python')
```

output:

```
   1      a  3  4
0  1      2  b  4
1  1  [a;b]  3  4
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KNyEbZ/2)

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. Could you enlighten me what the engine does? It seems not to be necessary. Thanks

Comment: @Towlie there are 2 csv parsers in `read_csv`. A fast C engine and a slower python engine. Only the python engine supports multichar/regex separators. It should be specified explicitly (raises a warning in recent pandas versions).